# Plugged vs plugged-in

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'd like to know if these two sentences:

> These Electric Vehicles (EVs) are plugged-in to domestic plugs, while
> those EVs are plugged-in to public charging stations. Both of them
> should be plugged-out at 6:00 p.m.

are correct.
In particular, my doubts are about:

- is it right to use the `hyphen`?
- is `plugged-in` correct, or should I use other forms (such as `plugged`, ...)?
- is `plugged-out` ok, or should I use other forms (such as `unplugged`, ...)?

Comment: Use "plugged in" and "unplugged". Where have you read "plugged-out"?

Comment: Thank you, got it! Honestly, I don't remember where I read "plugged-out", but, after reading [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204522/is-plugging-out-electronic-devices-an-american-expression), it seems to be a very uncommon expression, used in Ireland, and a few other countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *plug* can mean two very different things:

- something that blocks a pipe or other conduit carrying fluid, etc.

  - Context is typically plumbing or piping.
- something on the edge of cable that connects it to a socket.

  - Context is typically electrical.

Plain non-phrasal *plug* will typically imply something to do with plumbing or pipes.

> The drain is plugged with hair.

*Plug in*, or *plug up* in some cases, will typically imply an electrical context.

> The power cord is plugged in the wall.

*Plugged up* sometimes means *plug in*, especially if we're talking about a job or setup process with connecting cords to sockets, but it can also refer to something being clogged, so context is important for *plug up*.

> I plugged up all the cords.  What's next (setup or job context)

> The bathtub is plugged up so no water is getting out.

*Plugged out* does not mean a cord is disconnected from an outlet.  The best it could mean is that there's some blockage in a pipe outside, but even then it's somewhat awkward.

Also none of these use the hyphen.

Comment: Ok, thank you, very clear!
Another question: in my specific case: "`plugged into` domestic plugs/charging stations" could be a good alternative to "`plugged in to` domestic plugs/charging stations"?